# Vuetify v-alert not showing when reactive property is updated

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to conditionally render a v-alert if the login response code equals 401 Unauthorized. I have the alert defined below:

```
<v-alert v-if="this.show" type="error">Invalid email and/or password.</v-alert>
```

In the data section of my component, I define the property `show` which is by default set to false to not show the v-alert:

```
export default {
  name: "logincomponent",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {},
      show: false,
    };
  },
```

In the methods section of my component, I attempt user authentication and if the status code equals 401, I update `this.show = true`:

```
methods: {
    login: function() {
      let user = {
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password
      };
      authService.login(user).then(auth => {
        if (auth.response.status === 401) {
          this.show = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I would have thought this to work as `show` is reactive since it's defined in the `data()` section of my component.

Any idea what I can do to get this conditionally rendering properly?

Many thanks in advance,
Chappie Johnson

Comment: please share how do you're calling login method

Comment: i am calling the login method from the `methods` section.

Comment: please show how you're calling it like `this.login()` or `@click="login"`

Comment: I am doing `@click="login"`

Comment: try `this.$forceUpdate();` after `this.show = true;`

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately.  It's worth noting i can force the alert to show by setting `show: true` in the data section of my component. But I need it to be dynamic based on response code

Comment: please check my edited answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the `this` keyword from template  :

```
 <v-alert v-if="show" type="error">Invalid email and/or password.</v-alert>
```

if this doesn't work try a `show` computed property based on status :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      status: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    show() {
      return this.status === 401;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login: function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.status = 401;
        console.log(this.show)
      }, 3000)

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-btn small color="primary" @click="login">Login</v-btn>
  <v-alert v-if="show" type="error" >
    Invalid email and/or password
  </v-alert>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that you enter the scope of `(auth.response.status === 401)`?

Comment: Yes. If I console.log(auth.response.status) I can see 401 being printed to the console

Comment: try with `==` not with triple equality `===`

Comment: `==` is not giving desired results either

Comment: did you try to output `this.show` inside the condition scope?

Comment: Yes. It is outputting `true` to the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198429/discussion-between-chappie-johnson-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: I had an axios global intercepor that redircted any 401s to the home page and in my login function I was redirecting 401s to the login page.  This was causing a 401 on the login page to redirect to the home page and then back to login page very quickly, which was masking the alert showing itself.  I adjusted my axios global interceptor to handle 401s more appropriately. Thanks for the help!